# http-Link on Plotly Dash is not showing in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am using plotly dash to produce an interactive Dashboard at the browser. Since I am at work, I have to use what we have and have no opportunity to upgrade/downgrade the programs.
I am using Python 3.11 and Spyder IDE 3 (there is no Spyder 5 for me at work).
Usually, before I got Python 3.11, I run my code and in the console there was a "Running on [http://127.0.0.1:8050/"](http://127.0.0.1:8050/%22).
Now I only get:

[image]

When I go to the http-site, there are my plots and I can see everything I want, but there is no link at the console.
Can someone help me to change this?

Here is some code I use:

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from IPython.display import display

pio.renderers.default = "browser"

### generate table
def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return html.Table([
        html.Thead(
            html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])
        ),
        html.Tbody([
            html.Tr([
                html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
            ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))
        ])
    ])

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H1("Übersicht: Risp und Inzidenzen - Datengrundlage"),
                html.P("Kriterium"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="kriteriumsdropdown",
                    options=[
                        {"label": i, "value": i}
                        for i in zs.Kriterium.drop_duplicates()
                    ],
                    value="Geschlecht",
                ),
                html.P("Einheit"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="einheitdropdown",
                    options=[
                        {
                            "label": "Anzahl",
                            "value": "Anzahl",
                        },
                        {"label": "Prozent", "value": "Prozent"},
                    ],
                    value="Prozent",
                ),
                dcc.Graph(id="Ohne Differenzierung"),
                html.H4(children='Übersicht Durchschnitte'),
                generate_table(zs_alter_durchschnitt)
            ]
        ),
        html.Div(
            [html.H2("Platzhalter")]
        ),  # hier Layout für rechts einfügen (wenn das klappt), z.B. für Durchschnittsrente/Durchschnittsalter gesamt
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("Ohne Differenzierung", "figure"),
    [Input("einheitdropdown", "value"), Input("kriteriumsdropdown", "value")],
)
def updaten(einheitdropdown, kriteriumsdropdown):
    if kriteriumsdropdown == "Geschlecht":
        if einheitdropdown == "Prozent":
            figure1 = px.bar(
                mf,
                x="Konkret",
                y="Prozent",
                color="Konkret",
                barmode="group",
                labels={"Konkret": "Geschlecht"},
                # color_discrete_map= {"W": "pink", "M": "gray"}
                # wenn y stetig und nicht diskret ist: color_continuos_scale = px.colors.diverging.Picnic, range_color = [1,1000]
            )
        if einheitdropdown == "Anzahl":
            figure1 = px.bar(
                mf,
                x="Konkret",
                y="Anzahl",
                color="Konkret",
                barmode="group",
                labels={"Konkret": "Geschlecht"},
            )
        return figure1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8050)
```